# The created cell is wider then it should be.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating a cell:

```
-(AnswerTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AnswerTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AnswerTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.answersTable.frame.size.width, [self tableView:nil heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath])];
    }

NSLog(@"cell.frame - %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
NSLog(@"self.answersTable.frame - %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.answersTable.frame));


    AnswerObject* answer = self.question.answers[indexPath.row];

    CGFloat height = [self tableView:nil heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setupAnswerTableViewCell:self.question answer:answer row:indexPath.row height:height];

    return cell;
}
```

I see only a half of it.

When I print the cell and the table frames, I can see that the table is thiner then the cell. How did it happened?

```
2014-03-20 21:36:22.478 Theory[43601:60b] cell.frame - {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
2014-03-20 21:36:22.479 Theory[43601:60b] self.answersTable.frame - {{20, 38.880001068115234}, {280, 500}}
```

Comment: Are you creating your table by code? can you post it?

Comment: Where is `CellIdentifier` set? And please post the code for the `setupAnswerTableViewCell:answer:row:height:` method

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the `tableViewCell` that has the wrong frame, but the `tableview`. In case of `UITableView`, its `rows` will always have the same width as the `tableView` itlself.

BTW you really should not use `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` since it's deprecated. (And especially not `nitWithFrame:` method, how will your `cell` know about its `reuseIdentifer`?) You should use `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` instead if you are creating your cells programmatically.

Also calling

```
[self tableView:nil heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is very wrong. If you pass `tableView` in the parameter it will cause an infinite loop, that's probably the reason why you are passing nil. You can extract the code  in your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` into a separate method and call in both cases. But you really should trust your `cell` to adjust the layout of its content based on its `height`, so you **really should not deal with** `cell` `frame` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your cell using this initializer

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

This is the usual init in cells, so you do not need frame.

// You need to get the cell height from the answer text and return it in this method as `CGFloat` (Something like this example)

```
-(CGFloat)getAnswerHeightForCell:(Aswer *)answer {
       NSString *text = answer.text;
       CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width - PADDING * 3, 1000.0f)];

      return textSize.height ;
}
```

In your dataSource and delegate methods of the tableView you need to add the height of the cell and create the cell.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     Answerobject * answer = [self.question.answers[indexPath.row];
     CGFloat answeSize = [self getAnswerHeightForCell:answer ];

     return textSize.height + SOME_EXTRA_HEIGHT_FOR_PADDING;
}


-(AnswerTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AnswerTableViewCell *cell =( AnswerTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[LZCommentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    AnswerObject* answer = self.question.answers[indexPath.row];


    [cell setupAnswerTableViewCell:self.question answer:answer row:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```